# Unable to persist a sockets array upon user connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, server

I have these two files:

**io.js:**

```
var io = require('socket.io')();

var socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');
var jwtSecret = require('./settings').jwtSecret;

io.set('authorization', socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: jwtSecret,
  handshake: true
}));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    IO.pushSocket(socket);

});

var IO = module.exports = {
    io: io,
    sockets: [],
    pushSocket: function(socket) {
        if (typeof IO.sockets === 'undefined') {
            IO.sockets = [];
        }
        IO.sockets.push(socket);
        console.log(IO.sockets);
    }
}
```

**main.js:**

```
var sockets = require('./io').sockets;
console.log(sockets); \\ output is []
```

As you may notice, upon user connection I am trying to push to the sockets array in the IO module. But when I log the array in main.js it always returns as empty array. Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't create the array yet.

Comment: I am actually creating it in function pushSocket in case it is undefined

Comment: But that didn't happen yet.

Comment: man I am logging IO.sockets inside pushSocket function, and it shows that the socket has been pushed to the array, and I am running main.js way after that :|

Comment: How are you running main.js? That is very unlikely to be true.

Comment: Yea you're right, main.js is reading sockets array at a time where sockets array is empty. But my problem is, how to track changes in that array between files ?

Comment: Raise an event or call a function.

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching `require('./io').sockets` before the code (in `pushSocket()`) actually creates the array.

You cannot read an array before it exists.

You probably want to create the array immediately, so it will exist before you try to read it.

Comment: ok I see your point, but my aim is to "watch" the sockets array in io.js . How can I go about doing that ? I mean I want main.js to track every change in sockets array.

Comment: Even though I create sockets array inside module.exports like so [ ] , it always returns as empty array in main.js

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a bit of a different solution.  You don't need to keep track of your own array of connected sockets at all because socket.io already does that for you.  It provides both an array of sockets and a map of sockets (indexed by socket id):

```
// io.js
var io = require('socket.io')();

var socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');
var jwtSecret = require('./settings').jwtSecret;

io.set('authorization', socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: jwtSecret,
  handshake: true
}));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // whatever you want to do here
});

module.exports = io;
```

Then, to use that module, you can do this:

```
// main.js:
var io = require('./io');


// then sometime later AFTER some sockets have connected
console.log(io.sockets.sockets);        // array of connected sockets
```

Here are some of the data structures you can use from the `io` object:

```
io.sockets.sockets             // array of connected sockets
io.sockets.connected           // map of connected sockets, with socket.id as key
io.nsps                        // map of namespaces in use
io.nsps['/'].sockets           // array of connected sockets in the "/" namespace (which is the default)
io.nsps['/'].connected         // map of connected sockets in the "/" namespace
```

---

If you want to then track connect and disconnect events from outside the io module, you can just directly subscribe to the `connection` and `disconnect` events without having to invent your own scheme for it:

```
// main.js:
var io = require('./io');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // new socket just connected
    console.log(io.sockets.sockets);        // array of connected sockets            

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        // socket just disconnected
    });
});
```

Comment: @georgehelou - Did this provide a good solution to your issue?

Comment: Actually io.sockets.connected always returns as an empty object outside the io.on('connection') wrapper. This is why I opted in the first place for this solution...

Comment: hey @jfriend00. actually I opted for your solution. The problem (I guess) is that main.js is requiring io module before the connection is made. So when I do io.sockets.connected it is empty. Any idea how can I overcome this ?

Comment: `io.sockets.connected` reports the number of sockets connected at that moment.  You can use it anywhere, but if you use it during your server initialization, then no sockets are connected yet so it will show empty.  To know when you should reference it, we'd have to know what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: ok I have a script running all time and this script requires io module. Whenever a specific event happens, I want to send messages via sockets to my connected users. I am requiring io module during the server initialization but I am not using `io.sockets.connected` until way after that.

Comment: To send a message to all your connected users, you can just do `io.emit(msg, data)` and socket.io will handle sending it to all currently connected usersn - you don't have to do that manually.  If you are using the correct `io` object, then `io.sockets.connected` will show you all the connections that are present at that moment.  If you are seeing an empty array, then either you have the wrong `io` object or there are no currently connected users.

Comment: BTW, is your socket.io server stand-alone?  Or is there a webserver also?  I ask because `var io = require('socket.io')();` creates a stand-alone socket.io server.  Is that really what you intend?  Usually, in node.js apps a socket.io server is sharing an Express web server and you'd have to pass that server to socket.io when you initialize it.  Do you know for sure that your clients are successfully connecting to your socket.io server?  How do you know that?