# Asynchronous socket.io module sharing among different files and scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, socket.io, server

I have laid out my project to look like the following

**io.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io')();

var socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');
var jwtSecret = require('./settings').jwtSecret;

io.set('authorization', socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: jwtSecret,
  handshake: true
}));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

});

module.exports = io;
```

**app,js**

```
var io = require('./io');

...

var server = http.createServer(app);

io.attach(server);

server.listen(33666);
```

Now I want to use the sockets in another script in order to send messages to the connected users like so:

**script.js**

```
var io = require('./io');
...
io.emit(event, msg);
```

My problem is that when I log `io.sockets.connected` inside **script.js** it always returns as an empty object. I have narrowed down my problem, and I believe this is happening because when requiring the **io** module inside **script.js**, **io.js** is running again and therefore I am instantiating a new **io** object.
Any idea how can I overcome that problem?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks pretty much the same as your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196031/unable-to-persist-a-sockets-array-upon-user-connection.  As I said there, when you actually have some successful socket.io connections connected to your server, then `io.sockets.sockets` will be an array of connected sockets.  If you say the array is empty, then you have to prove to us/show us why you think there are actually connected sockets, but the array is empty.  I don't believe that there are connected sockets and the array is empty.

Comment: If you're doing `console.log(io.sockets.connected)` inside of scripts.js, then it's probably BEFORE there are actually any connected sockets.  You don't show us that actual code so we can't help you fix the important part of the problem.  This now looks like a dup of your previous question that you just decided to post again after incorporating a few things from the other answers, but still not fixing the germaine issue of when you examine `io.sockets.connected`.

Comment: The rest of the explanation lies in code you haven't shown us.  What does it means that "script.js is being run way after the node server has been launched"?  How/when is it run?  Are you sure there's only one io.js file?  Show us the ACTUAL code that loads scripts.js and show us the ACTUAL code in scripts.js where you don't get the right answer.  You just aren't showing us enough for us to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.js` file is the one that initializes your socket server, therefore you have to require it in `script.js` file:

```
var io = require('./io');
require('./app');
...
io.emit(event, msg);
```

BTW, node caches all requires, so you suspicion about node "running again" your `io.js` file is actually not true - the only thing that the second call to `require('./io')` does is returning your `io` instances reference.

Comment: hello @mdziekon, actually I did opt for the solution you offered. But then I ran into another problem. 
script.js is a worker script and will be spawned many many times in my application. Therefore I am getting Error: listen EADDRINUSE after spawning many workers since they are all requiring app.js . Any other work around?

Comment: @georgehelou I'm assuming you're talking about multiple processed being spawned. In that case, you should know that a single listening port can be used only by one OS process at a time. To overcome this problem in ``node``, you should check out [Cluster API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html) which let's you share single port across multiple application "instances".

Comment: yea maybe I am wrong about the module being run again, but I am pretty sure that I am getting another reference to the io object being exported. This is the only explanation of the fact that I am getting no connected sockets. Do you have any idea how to overcome that without requiring app.js in script.js ?

Comment: yea @mdziekon i know that. But my problem is not there. All I want to do is to share the io object across many files without running the module again and getting another io object.

Comment: Could you please post the exact code of you checking the ``io.sockets.connected`` property?

Comment: `console.log(io.sockets.connected);`

Comment: inside **script.js**  @mdziekon

Comment: Ok, so it appears that you synchronously try to read this variable. It will **always** be empty when read from the code that initializes the socket server. Try reading it on successful connection instead (in a handler, that is).

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to do it in a handler ? sorry but I am new to this kind of things and I've been stuck on that for like 3 days...

Comment: Try putting this ``console.log(...)`` inside ``io.on('connection', ...)`` handler.

Comment: yeah that will definitely solve it. But my issue is that I want to use io object inside **script.js** not **io.js**. So just to make things clear.. you're saying that it will always be empty when read from the code that initializes the socket server. But this is not true, I am initializing in **app.js** and reading in **script.js**. or you do mean that the require happens before connections ?

Comment: any thoughts? @mdziekon

Comment: Ok, it's clear to me now that you do not understand the asynchronous nature of node and it's libraries. It's really hard to explain this in a simple comment, so you should try to Google some examples of how to use things like socket.io with it's event handlers.

Comment: No man I do understand the nature of node, but my problem here is how to access the connected sockets somewhere outside the `io.on('connection',...)` handler; I am exporting the object, requiring in a different script and trying to access the sockets the way I already showed you. Do you have any suggestion on how to do that properly?

Comment: I've read a lot about socket.io handlers and I know how it works, but I am pretty frustrated about the fact that the io object is always empty in **script.js** @mdziekon

Comment: @georgehelou - It's all about timing.  You have to look at the `io` object AFTER some clients have connected.  They don't connect instantly so if you look at that value in the startup code for scripts.js, it will be empty.  But, if you look at it sometime later on some event after some clients have connected to your server, then it will show connected clients.  And, you also may need to make sure your clients actually are connecting successfully.

Comment: hey @jfriend00. Actually I am so confused due to the fact that `script.js` is being run way after the node server has been launched. And still when I require `io.js` at the top of my script, io is returned as an empty object. Note: if I log the connected users inside `io.on('connection',...)` I can see the successfully connected user. I guess but I am not sure that I am missing something fundamental to node here and the way files are required.